# @font-face: src called from HTML not from CSS (joomla)

Tags: html, css, joomla, font-face, src

The Allura Google font is working fine on my joomla website. This is the code stored in typo.css that I use:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font allura';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Allura'), local('Allura-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/allura/v2/ExiT4hKozv4E-LiOi2vvJA.woff) format('woff');
}

.allura{ font-family: 'font allura'; font-weight: bold; }
```

For some reasons, I would like to be able to call directly this font from within my article. So I created an article with this HTML:

```
<p style="font-family: font allura; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('Allura'), local('Allura-Regular'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/allura/v2/ExiT4hKozv4E-LiOi2vvJA.woff') format('woff');">Font generated from the article, without accessing the CSS</p>
```

But it's not working, and I end up with the default font. I have also tried without more success:

```
<p style="font-family: font allura; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src= "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/allura/v2/ExiT4hKozv4E-LiOi2vvJA.woff";">test direct dans article</p>
```

Any idea why and what should I do to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

P.S: I now it's bad practice (as it's better to organised everything from css), but I really need to do this that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include the font description, with `src: ...`, into a `style` attribute, since that attribute has [special limited syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/).

So you need the `@font-face` rule in a `style` element or in a linked stylesheet. If needed for some technical reason, you can, in practice, place a `style` element right before a `p` element; by the specifications, a `style` element must appear in a `head` element, but in practice it works in `body` too.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much Jukka! I didn't not the difference between style element and style attribut so for newbie like me, see the next answer for the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you need to enclose the font name in single quotes so

```
<p style="font-family: font allura; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('☺'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/allura/v2/ExiT4hKozv4E-LiOi2vvJA.woff') format('woff');">Font generated from the article, without accessing the CSS</p>
```

should be

```
<p style="font-family: 'allura'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('☺'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/allura/v2/ExiT4hKozv4E-LiOi2vvJA.woff') format('woff');">Font generated from the article, without accessing the CSS</p>
```

Comment: it could be the reason not using the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pattle! I try your code but still it's not working. @ShivanRaptor: What is font CSS short code?  I wonder if the problem is not with the src ( as my src for image are written : `<img src="..." />` but if I do that my code is wripped out.

Comment: @Pattle Still no success. Here is my [article](http://rscmovement.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=364&lang=fr)

Comment: @Arone ahh sorry you need to change `'font allura'` to just `'allura'` #gotthereintheend

Comment: Thanks a lot Pattle! You're a genius! I though the font-family name was up to me (well maybe it's just with the css way of doing it!). Thanks so much!!!

Comment: One lats thing: can I delete `local('☺'),` in `src` or is it mandatory?

Comment: @Pattle `font-family` should consist of at least 1 fallback font, such as `sans-serif`

Comment: Well actually it's not working... it did work because meanwhile our "conversation" I changed my css font-family from `font allura` to `allura`. 
So when you asked me to change `p style="font-family: 'font allura';` to `p style="font-family: 'allura';` the article just called the font family from the css not from the link in the html. Then I was so happy to see the result that I completely forgot what I did! Sorry @Pattle!

Answer (score 0):

Code based on Jukka K. Korpela answer:

```
<style>
         .allura{
            font-family:'font allura';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Allura'), local('Allura-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/allura/v2/ExiT4hKozv4E-LiOi2vvJA.woff)format('woff');
            }

</style>

<p class="allura">Font generated from the article, without accessing the CSS</p>
```